# Can I install current version of ubuntu on a Dell Inspiron mini 10 (CPU=Atom Z530)?

Tags: dell

Hopefully this is an easy question for the collected knowledge here.  I have an old Dell Inspiron mini 10 with a Atom Z530 CPU.  I am interested in installing ubuntu on it to run Kodi.

Due to it being 6 years old, would it be able to run the current version of ubuntu?  If it can, I'm looking at upping the RAM from 1Gb to 2Gb and installing a solid-state harddrive if it can handle that.

Answer (score 0):

I've run it on worse.  It should run the latest versions of Ubuntu fine, but it may be a little slow.  I would go with Lubuntu, since it's lighter-weight.

In short, yes, but it will be a tad slow.  Go with Lubuntu for better results.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the post edit (muru) and the post reply (Daniel).  I think I'll try Ubuntu 14.04 Server Installation Minimal and, if it's too slow, go with the Lubuntu per your suggestion, Daniel.

Comment: If this answer worked for you, you can mark it accepted (or perhaps not, now that it's a duplicate?).